# How to load dynamic content in JSF table

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, javabeans

I have a webpage with a table layout in it which is develop using JSF. The data, including header and content value, inside the table should be dynamically load. My current challenge is different source coming into this JSF page will have different row's of records. May I know how this can be done? Am I require a Java Bean to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use beans for that. Usually the content of the table will go from the database. So in the datatable you can just use `value="#{yourbean.contentList}"`. And the `contentList` will be retrieved based on the id of the desired data which can be set by the request params.

Answer (score 0):

JSF datatable do not have a limit on the number of rows. If there are a large number of rows the browser may not handle it well, use paging to limit the number of rows http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/10/effective-datatable-paging-and-sorting.html

If there are different numbers of columns (not rows) in the data then dynamically generate datatable  http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html#PopulateDynamicDatatable

Thanks to BalusC!